# Porting Java to Javascript, Getter & Setter vs Direct Acces

Tags: java, javascript, oop, setter, getter

I am trying to port a Java program to Javascript.

In java, there are these simplified classes.

**Source.java**

```
public class Source {
  private final int width;
  private final int Height;

  public Source(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height= height;
  }
}
```

**Binarizer.java**

```
public abstract class Binarizer {
  private Source source;

  protected Binarizer (Source  source) {
    this.source = source;
  }

  public final int getSource() {
    return source;
  }
}
```

**HistogramBinarizer.java**

```
public class HistogramBinarizer extends Binarizer {

  protected HistogramBinarizer (Source  source) {
    super(source);
  }

  public int getWidth() {
    Source source = getSource();
    return source.getWidth();
  }
}
```

And in javascript, i have the following.

**Source.js**

```
function Source(width, height) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
}

Source.prototype.getWidth = function () {
  return this.width;
}

Source.prototype.getHeight = function () {
  return this.height;
}
```

**Binarizer.js**

```
function Binarizer (source) {
  this.source = source;
}

Binarizer.prototype.getSource = function () {
  return this.source;
}
```

**HistogramBinarizer.js**

```
function HistogramBinarizer (source) {
  Binarizer.call(this, source);
}

HistogramBinarizer.prototype = Object.Create(Binarizer.prototype);

HistogramBinarizer.prototype.getWidth = function () {
  var source = this.getSource();
  return source.getWidth();
}
```

My question is that since these javascript 'classes' don't have private variables, should I just use `return this.source.getWidth()` in `HistogramBinarizer.prototype.getWidth` ? My goal is to keep the ported version as close to the source version as possible. What are the advantages/disadvantages of both sides?

I am also aware of the closure method to create private variables, but this program is to be run several times per second processing pixels of a live video stream, and that method is a lot slower than prototype method.

Answer (score 0):

In general I would suggest you to drop your concerns about keeping the JS design equal to your Java design because you'll end up wasting a lot of time implementing wrong JS design that will lead to bugs.

If I would stick to your example without changing the overall design I would keep using the getter.
It doesn't matter whether your member is private or not its a good practice to use interface over implementation.
Especially with JS where you could easily change your Source.java interface ending up breaking your dependencies. Only in JS you don't have a compiler to alert you like in Java.